# Создание теста

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу создать тест.
В БД имею 200 вопросов, по 3-4 вариантов ответа в каждом. 
Выводить буду случайных 20 вопросов.

Вопрос: Как отвечать пользователю и как его ответы потом сравнить с правильными ответами?
Перед каждым вариантом ответа поставить радио-кнопку, то как это связать с вариантами ответов. 
Как и где лучше хранить правильный ответ?
+ расположение вариантов ответа всегда меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

храни в отдельной таблице вопросы:

questions:

id | question

и отдельно ответы:

answers:

id | question_id | answer

ну и тут уже сравнивать просто, и правильных вариантов к одному вопросу может быть уйма.

Comment: answer Хранить целиком полностью ответ?
Когда пользователь будет работать со страницей Как обработчик узнает на какой вопрос что ответил юзер?
Передавать обработчику полностью текст ответа? 
Через value возможно это смогу сделать, но слишком много информации передается.

Comment: по ИД-вопросу узнает, вы главное правильно его передайте, да получается ИД вопроса + текст ответа на сервер (хотя можно и ИД ответа только). Я когда делал "Кто хочет стать миллионером", аналог игры то в базе было |id|otv_a|otv_b|otv_c|otv_d|prav| в последнем поле был вариант правильного ответа (напр. otv_c), но у вас вроде как их несколько может быть, если немного подняпрячься, то в ячейку prav записвыать номер ответа (или ИД, не знаю что там вы планируете) через запятуй несколько, потом просто, хотел сказать explode'ом разбивать, но подумал что даже регуляркой распарсить на наличие вполне ок

Comment: Не понимаю как связать радио-кнопки с вариантом ответа. 
Если у меня 200 вопросов. У каждого вопроса id-шники ответов повторяются же. ПОлучается еще надо как то радио-кнопке привязать вопрос.
Через name что ли? Или др. варианты есть?

Comment: ну да, через name